# pyqt - loading user data, how to avoid using global variable?

Tags: python, pyqt, global-variables

I'm making a fairly simply UI using PyQt5 that will allow a user to open a folder of data and then plot different parts of that data as they wish. I'm a bit stuck, though, on how to make the data that is imported after selecting the "Import Data" button available to other parts of the widget without using a global

Code

```
class DataViewer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUI(self)

    def setupUI(self, Form):
        Form.resize(1742, 988)
        Form.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.PreventContextMenu)
        Form.setWindowTitle("Data Viewer")

        self.windowLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.windowLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_window")

        self.leftColumn = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.leftColumn.setObjectName("leftColumnLayout")

        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(Form)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")

        self.loadDataFolder_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Load Data Folder", Form)
        self.loadDataFolder_btn.setObjectName("loadDataFolder_btn")

        self.loadDataFolder_btn.clicked.connect(self.load_data_folder)

        self.leftColumn.addWidget(self.treeWidget)
        self.leftColumn.addWidget(self.loadDataFolder_btn)

        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")

        self.plotWidget = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(Form)
        self.plotWidget.setObjectName("plotWidget")

        self.windowLayout.addLayout(self.leftColumn)
        self.windowLayout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.windowLayout.addWidget(self.plotWidget, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    def load_data_folder(self):
        folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)
        df = pvi.import_folder(folder)
```

Note - pvi.import is just a function from another module I've written that deals with the data files our data collection software generates.

I'm sure there is an obvious way to do this, but I'm very new to this (learning as I go).

Thanks

Comment: Why not just: `self.df = pvi.import_folder(folder)`?

Comment: yup that works, although I'll be honest it's not entirely clear to me why. need to go read a bit more about classes I think

if you put that into an answer I'll mark as correct. thanks

Comment: nothing to do with class, if you make df a local variable of a function, it will be garbage collected when the function return, by making it an object attribute (self.df) of your gui object, it will exists a reference to your data as long as your gui exists, that's why it works (if the desired lifetime of your data is the same than your gui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your instance of `DataViewer` as a namespace to store the imported data rather than using a global:

```
def load_data_folder(self):
    folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)
    self.df = pvi.import_folder(folder)
```

The data can then by accessed via `self` by any of the other methods of `DataViewer`.